# JBoss AS 7.1.1 - Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name CDI Conversation Filter

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, cdi

I am getting the following exception when I deploy my application to a JBoss AS 7.1.1.

I don't have any issues with the CDI Conversation Filter when deploying the same application to Glassfish 3 or 4.

```
22:53:33,911 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context [/basic-angularjs-ee] startup failed due to previous errors: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name CDI Conversation Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2040) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:1996) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.processWebMetaData(JBossContextConfig.java:314) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(JBossContextConfig.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:417) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:182) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:162) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3790) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CDI Conversation Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the filter name is platform specific.  The default mapping for the filter though is `/*`, so do you really need to change the mapping?

Comment: I get exceptions from my long polling servlets if I put the mapping on root

Comment: Also I cannot find any information regarding CDI Conversation Filter other then Weld. Do you have any other pointers?

Comment: I'm wondering, are you sure this worked on GlassFish 3? According to the docs, the name you're using is only available in CDI 1.1 (GF4, WildFly 8).  See here: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.1.2.Final/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1964

Comment: upps, my GF3 configuration was indeed pointing at the GF4 installation. I guess for CDI 1.0 (JEE6) I will have to resort to Weld specific Filter implementation WeldCrossContextFilter.java

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the classname as it is written inside the project that filter is going to use. Not with spaces and case sensitive. that looks like the issue.